# Analysing Space Complexity

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, space-analysis

I have to compute the space complexity of this function:

```
double foo(int n){
     int i;
     double sum;
     if(n==0) return 1.0;
     else
          for(i=0;i<n;i++)
              sum+= foo(i);
     return sum 
}
```

What I have done:

When function is called, the activation record is created on the call stack. For $foo(n)$ let the size of AR be $x$.

- $foo(0)$ does not place any recursive calls.
- $foo(1)$ places 1 recursive call. Terminates at $foo(0)$.
- $foo(2)$ places 2 recursive calls to $foo(0)$ and $foo(1)$.
- $foo(1)$ places another recursive call. 
  Therefore total calls placed is 2+1.
- $foo(3)$ places 3 recursive calls to $foo(0)$,$foo(1)$ and $foo(2)$. Therefore total calls placed is $3+0+1+3= 7$ recursive calls.
- $foo(4)$ places 4 recursive calls. $4+0+1+3+7= 15$.

Hence we can see that $foo$ produces calls in the pattern: 0,1,3,7,15,31,...

This shows us that $foo(n)$ produces $(2^n)-1$ recursive calls.

If we count the total no. of recursive calls made by $foo(n)$ it becomes a geometric series and evaluates to approximately $(2^n)-n$.

Hence I am getting Space complexity to be $O(2^n)$.

However several books have merely listed the answer as $O(n!)$ without giving an explanation. I just want to know where I am going wrong in my approach.

Comment: What's your unit; bits or (arbitrary-size) words?

Comment: The time complexity is $\Theta(2^n)$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In my opinion you are not quite right...

During the loop, when you return from `foo(i)`, the spaces used by the call `foo(i)` is released (I mean, the stack pointer is back to the previous position).

So actually `foo(i)` only uses `1` more AR than `foo(i - 1)`. The space cost should be `O(n)`.

This can be verified by running the code with `foo(25)` and specify a stack of size `1 MB` (disable all optimizations, of course). It will return normally within several seconds, without "stackoverflow". This is a proof that it's not using O(2^n) space.

Comment: You are right, the recursive calls are not at the same time, thus the space is linear (at the worst moment foo(n) is running foo(n-1) which is running .. foo(1) : n functions foo are in the stack)

Comment: Thank you. Should have used the recursion tree and call stack method.